# set the thumbnail width and height in xuggler

Tags: java, xuggle

i am using xuggler to obtain the thumbnail of a video file amd the image is created by xuggler in dimension 640*480 but i want to image size in 200*200 or 2--*2-- if it possible then please tell me and how i do it.

Answer (score 1):

You could just resize it in java with:

```
BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, type);
Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, null);
g.dispose()
```